# what the jar file for the SystemFile.getLocal()?

Tags: java, jar, get, filesystems

I can not find the jar file for the class FileSystem.getLocal();

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path clusters = new Path(BASE_DIR, new Path("initial-clusters"));
```

I included all jar file from Hadoop but the compiler tells some problem about the class get not found

Comment: Code says FileSystem, title says SystemFile ... now what? (and hint: the compiler first looks for the class, the method to call is irrelevant).

Comment: Provide more details like build system you are using, import statements etc.

Comment: Just in case the answer is sufficient to solve the problem, please consider accepting it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

[jar-download.com](https://jar-download.com/maven-repository-class-search.php?search_box=org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem) suggests that you need the *hadoop-common* JAR.

So, ensure that

- you really have that JAR, too
- that your classpath setup is correct, so that the compiler can **find** that JAR, too

But the real answer would be: use a build system like maven or gradle, specify your [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common), and have the build system pull it for you.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. Sorry about the mistake, I mean FileSystem